# Automatically add a row or a value below the last non-empty / used row

Tags: excel, vba, addition, rows

In between the two 'table data download' sections, the number of rows of the first table is not fixed.

How to add the VBA script to enable it to automatically add five rows immediately after the last used row of the first table, and then start the second table download?

```
Sub GetFinanceData()
For x = 1 To 5
Dim URL As String, elemCollection As Object
Dim t As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer
Dim LastLine As Long
LastLine = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Stocks").Select
Worksheets("Stocks").Activate

'Open IE and Go to the Website

URL = "http://stock.finance.sina.com.cn/hkstock/finance/00001.html"
URL = Cells(x, 1)

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .navigate URL
    .Visible = True

Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4
    Loop
DoEvents

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stocks").Range("B" & x).Value

'Select the Report Type

Set selectItems = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")
For Each i In selectItems
    i.Value = "zero"
    i.FireEvent ("onchange")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Next i

Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K500").ClearContents

'Find and Get the First Table Data

Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 4)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t

'Find and Get the Second Table Data

Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 1 To (elemCollection.Length - 3)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 19, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t


'Find and Get the Third Table Data

Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 2 To (elemCollection.Length - 2)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 48, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t

'Find and Get the Fourth Table Data

Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 3 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 61, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
    Next c
    Next r
    Next t
End With

' cleaning up memory

IE.Quit

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok I'm picturing you starting with a blank sheet (after ClearContents) and then importing the first table to say rows 1 through 90 then importing table 2 to say rows 96 through 145. If I'm right, do you really want to _insert_ 5 rows or just increase your row counter by 5?? Just seems like a pointless operation if I understand your situation.

Comment: Hi Mark,  First table -->  Insert 5 rows --> Next table--> Insert 5 rows-->Next table, following this pattern. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another thing I can't seem to figure out. `For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 4)` If that set of three loops is solely to export the first table, why does the outer loop exist? Why not replace the outer loop with `t = 0`?

Comment: Hi, Mark sorry for the mislead, actually there are four tables, I just posted two fow simplified reason, now I updated the four complete tables, could you help again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want 5 rows of spacing between each table. That doesn't physically require adding rows. You already have blank rows beneath the table. I recommend just adding a variable `tblStartRow` that keeps track of the first row of the current table and uses that variable in the `Cells` call. I set that value to 1 for the first table and then calculate a new start row value for the second table.

```
'Find and Get the First Table Data

tblStartRow = 1
Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 4)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r + tblStartRow, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
        Next c
    Next r
Next t

'Find and Get the Second Table Data

tblStartRow = tblStartRow + r + 4
Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 1 To (elemCollection.Length - 3)
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r + tblStartRow, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
        Next c
    Next r
Next t
```

Furthermore I see no point in separating these tables into their own loop sets so I would combine all the table exports as (you'll notice I moved the statement where I reassign the value of `tblStartRow`):

```
tblNameArr = Array("Balance Sheet", "Cash Flow", "Header 3", "Header 4", "Header 5")
tblStartRow = 1
Set elemCollection = .Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
For t = 0 To elemCollection.Length - 1
    For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(r + tblStartRow, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
        Next c
    Next r
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r + tblStartRow + 2, 1) = tblNameArr(t)
    tblStartRow = tblStartRow + r + 4
Next t
```

I edited the last code block to export text in column A between tables per OP comment.

Comment: Hi, Mark, after testing, it works! Thanks so much! But what if I want to add  a value to the 3rd row of the 4 rows inserted, column A, is that possible? Each Value I want to add is different. Precisely speaking, the pattern is Table 1 →2 blank rows→1 row with a value in column A, e.g. "Balance Sheet"→1 Blank row→Table 2→2 blank rows→1 row with a value in column A, e.g. "Cash flow"→1 Blank row→Table 3,etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NicholasKan Take a look at the updated code. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @NicholasKan if the answer suits your problem, please accept it.

Comment: Yes! But cannot add Chinese character. OMG

Comment: Mark, below is the html code,
Would you help to set the code to get the values by tag/name/id? I want to set the value as the title of the tables, since I cannot type Chinese in VBA...T_T
Pattern:
Row 1 to Row 4, Blank, then
Starting from Row5: Value "a1" in column A
One blank rows
Table 1
Two blank rows
Value "a2" in column A
One blank rows
Table 2
Two blank rows
Value "a3" in column A
One blank rows
Table 3
Two blank rows
Value "a4" in column A
One blank rows
Table 4

Comment: -重要财务指标 end-->
  <!--资产负债表 start-->
    <a name="a2" id="a2"></a>
   <div class="part02">
      <div class="sub01">
              <div class="sub01_tt fblue">
                  <span class=""><a href="#a1" target="_self">重要财务指标</a></span>
                  <span class=" selected"><a href="#a2" target="_self">资产负债表</a></span>
                  <span class=""><a href="#a3" target="_self">现金流量表</a></span>
                  <span class=""><a href="#a4" target="_self">综合损益表</a></span>

Comment: @NicholasKan I think [this Office Support article]https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Turn-on-Chinese-language-features-40db0d4f-4bad-47d3-9eeb-bf80f9c3b5b1 should help. If not try to add them using the ChrW() and feeding it the unicode number associated with your desired character. If none of that works, I would ask that as a new question.